# horizontal scrolling responsive nav menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, nav

I'm trying to copy a portion of google's mobile site.

http://www.imgur.com/9DdQz.png

The area near the bottom of their site has their "places" menu, where you can scroll horizontally through different options using your fingers, then tap on the icon you'd like.

The features I'd like to copy are the horizontal scrolling, along with keeping the page set to a specific width so the window doesn't just re-size, thereby negating the scrolling feature.

I've tried to get a copy of the code used for creating this using the Android Remote Debugging tool for Chrome, but I can't find the specific code for this part of the website, I think it must load via a separate .js file. I've also done enough google searches that the prospect of trying another search string is on the same level as bashing my head into a brick wall in an attempt to redecorate my place of work. In short, I'm lost, out of my depth, and asking for help. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe they have only hidden the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Have you actually tried to write anything yourself, or do you just want someone to post up some completed code for you? I'd say you should make an attempt at it at least before you give up and ask for people to hand you code.

Comment: I am not a programmer, I am a marketing analyst, I have no idea what I am doing. None of this is in my job description, nor did I volunteer for this project. I did not try to write anything myself. The only reason I am even working on this is because the firm I work at is pushing me into this position to surport their lead developer. They are paying for my education, and for me to do this. I apologize if I offend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="scrollcontainer" >
    <div id="scrollplane" >
         <a class="nav" href="?">Link 1</a>
         <a class="nav" href="?">Link 2</a>
         <a class="nav" href="?">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#scrollcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto; 
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height: // some height
}

#scrollplane { 
 height: // less than scroll container ;
 width: // greater than scroll container;
```

}

I would then suggest styling your links positioned relatively across the scroll plane. this should achieve the desired effec on a mobile browser but will reveal a scroll bar on a desktop